# How to get a string variable in sql Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can someone help-me set up an SQL command that retrieves only the value of the first occurrence of "cost" in a string like the example below.

See below two results returned from a table where I store sql query execution plan. I use Postgres. The word cost always comes at the beginning, but it does not always come in the same position, so you can not simply do substring (...). I think you should find the initial and final position every time, to be able to extract only the cost value. If anyone can help me, the expected result for the example below is:

```
select (.... )
-----------------
cost=399301  (only this)
```

----------------------SAMPLE STRING SOURCE ------------------

```
Sort  (cost=399301.55..399301.57 rows=6 width=36)
  Sort Key: l_returnflag, l_linestatus
  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=399301.21..399301.48 rows=6 width=36)
        ->  Seq Scan on h_lineitem  (cost=0.00..250095.98 rows=5968209 width=36)
              Filter: (l_shipdate <= (to_date('1998/12/01'::text, 'YYYY/MM/DD'::text) - '10 days'::interval day))
```

-------------------- SECOND SAMPLE --------------------------------

```
Aggregate  (cost=7922058.70..7922058.71 rows=1 width=16)"
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=1899763.92..7922058.69 rows=1 width=16)"
        Hash Cond: (h_lineitem.l_partkey = h_part.p_partkey)"
        Join Filter: (((h_part.p_brand = 'Brand#13'::bpchar) AND (h_part.p_container = ANY ('{"SM CASE","SM BOX","SM PACK","SM PKG"}'::bpchar[])) AND (h_lineitem.l_quantity >= 4::double precision) AND (h_lineitem.l_quantity <= 14::double precision) AND (h_ (...)"
        ->  Seq Scan on h_lineitem  (cost=0.00..235156.84 rows=211094 width=32)"
              Filter: ((l_shipmode = ANY ('{AIR,"AIR REG"}'::bpchar[])) AND (l_shipinstruct = 'DELIVER IN PERSON'::bpchar))"
        ->  Hash  (cost=1183158.46..1183158.46 rows=35278997 width=33)
->  Seq Scan on h_part  (cost=0.00..1183158.46 rows=35278997 width=33) Filter: (p_size >= 1)"
```

---

Best Regards

Comment: I'm voting to close just because your formatting offends me. Try harder. This isn't your first rodeo.

Comment: Evan, the biggest goal of all here is the technical cooperation on programming issues, and not having a colorful and well-formatted text, this you call attention, it's a secondary question, I hope you understand the bigger goal of this forum. best regards

Comment: It's not just about you. I don't know you. I'm here to answer good questions efficiently for a community. Me answering this question can only help other people if you don't completely crap on formatting and presentation. So don't be a sociopath. If you can present your question better, do it. It helps those answering, and those in the future that have the same problem.

Comment: Aside from just formatting and presenting, we need EXPLAIN ANALYZE, not just EXPLAIN. EXPLAIN can help us out with the plan. But, we don't know where the problem is without the real world effect of the plan. EXPLAIN ANALYZE has all the information of EXPLAIN and more.

Comment: We also need the original query.

Comment: My question is how to mount an SQL command that returns only the value of the first cost, which is relative to the total cost, only that. If using explain or explain analyze is not important, I only need to know how to fetch only the cost in the sample string.

Comment: You mean you want to parse the query plan in SQL?

Comment: Yes, I need to store the total cost of the explain statement on a table of my own. So I need to extract only this value from the result of the EXPLAIN or EXPLAIN ANALYZE command. I do not need all the EXPLAIN command information, only the total cost. See above that I have edited the question for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the plans are stored in a table named `plan_table` in a column named `execution_plan` you can use the following:

```
select replace(substring(execution_plan from '\(cost=[0-9]+'), '(cost=', '')
from plan_table;
```

The `substring(...)` returns the first occurrence of `(cost=` and the `replace` is then used to remove that prefix.

Comment: Dear This sugestion was very good, but I adapted in postgresql, because this dbms not persist plan in table, only in memory or log (file text).  I Need of the value next " . . " for example:  cost=27726324.40..27726324.41.  I adapted the regular expression I get result this:   select substring('Aggregate  (cost=27726324.40..27726324.41' from '\[0-9]+.?[0-9]{2}') ;            RESULT   27726324.40   . But I need get value = 27726324.41  (next ..  two point)    .  Do you or another people  help in this question ?

Comment: I get success in code below (except the first point): select substring('Aggregate  (cost=27726324.40..27726324.41 Rows' from '\[.][0-9]+.?[0-9]{2}');    RESULT   .27726324.41    . But i would like the first point (.) not was show, and only number.  If anyone has any tips on how to get the point of begin.

Answer (score 0):

I get successful and the solution, the obcjetive was get the value 27726324.41, the Expression Regular final developted is:

```
select substring('Aggregate (cost=27726324.40..27726324.41 Rows' from '[.]Y*([0-9]+.?[0-9]{2})')
```

---

RESULT 27726324.41

Thanks a_horse_with_no_name and anothers that help-me.